# Calculate the days between dates in access in the same column and to hold latest code

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need some help please. I have beeing searching the net and have tried and still getting a "0" for answer.

```
orderid   accno   invdate       next date      days
1          a001   31/05/2016    03/06/2016     3
2          a001   03/06/2016    04/06/2016     2
3          a001   04/06/2016    02/06/2016        this is where it is wrong
4          a002   02/06/2016
```

I have tried the following

```
DateDiff("d",[InvDate],[NextDate]) AS Days
```

this is my sql in Access query

```
SELECT Rental.OrderID, Rental.AccNo, Rental.Customer, Rental.InvDate, Rental.Invoice, NZ(Sum([ArgD]+[ActD]+[OxgD])) AS QtyDel, NZ(Sum([ArgR]+[ActR]+[OxyR])) AS QtyRet, NZ(Sum(DSum("(ArgD+ActD+OxgD)-(ArgR+ActR+OxyR)+NZ([BF])","[Rental]","[Rental].[OrderID]=" & Rental.OrderID & " AND [Rental].[OrderID]<=" & Rental.OrderID))) AS RT, AllDays.InvDate, Sum(DSum("(ArgD+ActD+OxgD)-(ArgR+ActR+OxyR)+NZ([BF])","[Rental]","[Rental].[OrderID]=" & Rental.OrderID & " AND [Rental].[OrderID]<=" & Rental.OrderID)) AS DT, AllDays.NextDate, DateDiff("d",AllDays.InvDate,[NextDate]) AS DAYS, Rental.ArgD, Rental.ActD, Rental.OxgD, Rental.ArgR, Rental.ActR, Rental.OxyR, Rental.Period, Rental.Rate, Rental.InvRental, Rental.BF, Rental.BF, "cyl" AS str, "Days" AS cyldays, Rental.NitD, Rental.NitR, Rental.MagD, Rental.MagR, Rental.OtherD, Rental.OtherR
FROM (SELECT OrderID, AccNo, InvDate, Nz((SELECT     MIN(InvDate)   FROM Rental T2   WHERE T1.accno = T2.accno   AND T2.InvDate > T1.InvDate), DateSerial(YEAR(T1.InvDate), MONTH(T1.InvDate) + 1, 1)) AS NextDate FROM Rental AS T1)  AS AllDays INNER JOIN Rental ON AllDays.OrderID = Rental.OrderID
GROUP BY Rental.OrderID, Rental.AccNo, Rental.Customer, Rental.InvDate, Rental.Invoice, AllDays.InvDate, AllDays.NextDate, Rental.ArgD, Rental.ActD, Rental.OxgD, Rental.ArgR, Rental.ActR, Rental.OxyR, Rental.Period, Rental.Rate, Rental.InvRental, Rental.BF, Rental.NitD, Rental.NitR, Rental.MagD, Rental.MagR, Rental.OtherD, Rental.OtherR
ORDER BY Rental.OrderID;
```

Comment: I see no _NextDate_ values.

Comment: hi gustav AllDays.NextDate, DateDiff("d",[AllDays].[InvDate],[NextDate]) AS Days

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter on a single `accno` only:

```
WHERE T1.accno = T2.accno And T2.InvDate > T1.InvDate) AS NextDate
```

Comment: how can i automatically update the blank next date to the last day of the current month

Comment: what i meant if the last record was 07/06/2016. at the end of the month i need to update that blank next date to 30/06/2016

Comment: Then that date is _Null_ which you can wrap with `Nz` - see edit.

Comment: tks. is there a closing bracket missing after nz

Comment: tks Gustav. works great. Only problem is if the invdate is 15/05/2016 i want the it to chose 31/05/2016 and if 02/06/2016 then 30/06/2016

Comment: wow. that seems to work however for eg if i continue with the next date from 02/06/2016 to 04/06/2016 then the next date for 02/06/2016 should be 04/06/2016. it shows 30/06/2016

Comment: sorry im back. Only problem is if the invdate is 15/05/2016 i want the it to chose 31/05/2016 . my next record is 02/06/2016. it take s 02/06/2016. i want may record to end with last day of may and june record to last day of june.

Comment: Uh, this goes in circles. However, `Nz kicks in when no `Min(InvDate)` is found, so you should be able to adjust it yourself.

Comment: Sorry Gustav. This is for cylinder rentals.The client is charged out monthed for the cylinders for the no of days it was wirh him. If a customer took 2 cylinder and returned 1 on 20/05/2016 , He will be billed from 20/05/2016 to 31/05/2016 for 1 cylinder at a daily rate.

Comment: and if his next transaction takes place on the 03/06/2016. He will be billed on the 30/06/2016.

Comment: Then, I guess, you will have to use the return date, not the invoice date in your calculations.

Comment: the problem is that most of them dnt return., the daily rate is r3.67 and a new cyliner r3000. so if a client has 10 cylinder of ours and three get empty he orders another three in exchange for the empties. if no wmpties he then gets added to his current bal

Comment: can i not use a case scenario with date serial. as soon as it is a new month the empty next date must be last date of that month

Comment: date      del       returned      bal       days

Comment: date         del    returned    bal   days
31/04/2016                        1    5   chagre from 01/05 to 05/05  1 for 5days
06/05/2016    5        2         3     2   charge for may 3cyl for 2days
08/05/2016    3        1         5     4   charge for may 5cyl for 4days
12/05/2016    7        11        1     20  chage  for may 1cyl for 20days 

01/06/2016    5         1        5

Comment: You can always obtain the last date of the month of a some date from this expression: `DateSerial(Year(SomeDate), Month(SomeDate) + 1, 0)`.

Comment: sorry Gustav. Im stuck.

Comment: Well, you have the bits and pieces, so start from scratch and add bit by bit.

Comment: hi. gustav i managed to get it working . there is one poblem . if there is two transaction for a client on the same day it does not add it as one. it gives me eg. running total is 22 and days is 9days. on 10/06/2016 client ordere 1 cyl and later that day another 1.

Comment: inv date     del       next date     total cyl        days

Comment: OK. Edit your question to also hold the latest code.

Comment: this is what its doing . if there was two trans on the 01/06/2016 the [next date] for the should be 01/06/2016 cos there is two for that day . the third trans is on the 20/06/2016.  it selects 01/06-20/06 and then 01/06-20/06.

Comment: id        accno   invdate   cyl    next date      days    totcyl
1          a01   31/05          3     04/06/2016    4          3     wrong here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2          a01   31/05         1      04/06/2016    4          4
3          a01   04/06         2      30/06/2016    26        6

Comment: OK. Edit your question to also hold the latest code. i dnt understand what you mean

Comment: We don't have your cylinders and data so it is close to impossible to follow your doings.

Comment: You can't. Either add to your question or - if it is the answer - create a new answer.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I added to my question